# Why does file-roller appear to have lower privileges than the user?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, samba, file-roller

In Ubuntu I have a mounted Samba share. I have selected some files in a directory on the Samba share in Nautilus and attempted to compress them to an archive in the same location. File Roller tells me I don't have permissions to create an archive here. Yet in Nautilus, I am free to view the directory contents, create directories in that location and create files in that location.

What permissions could I possibly be missing to create an archive here?

Answer (score 1):

Thats not a permission error. Its a bug in fileroller https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/file-roller/+bug/1071759
Sadly no one seems to be able to fix that. This bug exists since 2012.